# deg2rad conversion in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, haversine, loss

I am implementing a haversine loss function in my CNN (python 2.7.14, tensorflow 1.14.0). I am looking for a tf call that would convert degrees to radians. Is there such an api available? Could not find this in the tensorflow documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot find it in the docs, because it is simply (assume proper intervals):

```py
def deg2rad(deg):
    pi_on_180 = 0.017453292519943295
    return deg * pi_on_180


def rad2deg(rad):
    pi_on_180 = 0.017453292519943295
    return rad / pi_on_180
```

**edit**: Since you asked explicitly for the TensorFlow version:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
def tf_deg2rad(deg):
    pi_on_180 = 0.017453292519943295
    return deg * pi_on_180


def tf_rad2deg(rad):
    pi_on_180 = 0.017453292519943295
    return rad / pi_on_180

deg = tf.convert_to_tensor(90.)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_deg2rad(deg)))
```

Comment: This might not work inside a tensor in the loss function. I am looking for a tf.deg2rad or some equivalent of that.